# No rounded corners with background image in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, background-image

I try to make a corner of an anchor pane rounded that has an image as a background. For some reason if I use the image, the corner won't be rounded (I mean the corner of the pane maybe, but not the corner of the image). If I comment the image out, the corner is rounded.

```
#rootPane{
    /*-fx-background-image: url("background5standing.png");
    -fx-background-size: cover;*/
    -fx-background-radius:0 0 25 0;
    -fx-border-radius:0 0 25 0;
}
```

On the w3schools page they don't mention any special thing about it. They say that you just need to set the image, and make the corners rounded... Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This feature is not supported in JavaFX yet and has already been answered at [Border-Radius and Shadow on ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489908/border-radius-and-shadow-on-imageview)