# how to change the background radius of a image view?

Tags: java, javafx

My question is about making round background radius to a javafx imageview.
I've tried to wrap into an anchorPane which had the good radius but the image is still over and not round.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border-Radius and Shadow on ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489908/border-radius-and-shadow-on-imageview)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrote some css to this matter. You can write a class for that and link this css to the imageview

. image-round{

border radius :100%;

}